# Grammatical Functions

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical name of "that has come in contact" in the following sentence:

> The disease can be spread from an infected person to a healthy one through direct contact with the patient's body or any article that has come in contact with the patient.

Comment: That's a *restrictive relative clause* used adjectivally modifying the antecedent *any article*.

Comment: @StoneyB Well, I think I should rephrase my comment, "that has come in contact with the patient" is a restrictive relative clause used adjectivally modifying the antecedent any article. Does it look better?

Comment: Actually, the relative clause modifies just the noun "article" (i.e. excluding the determiner "any").

Answer (score 4):

> The disease can be spread from an infected person to a healthy one through direct contact with ... any article [that has come in contact with the patient].

The string *that has come in contact with the patient* is a relative clause. In terms of functions, it is a postmodifier of the noun *article*.

According to grammars such as the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, it would be an *integrated* relative clause. These are also known as *restrictive*  or *defining* relative clauses in other grammars.

Answer (score 2):

The disease can be spread from an infected person to a healthy one through direct contact with the patient's body or any article **that has come in contact with the patient.**

It is *restrictive or limiting relative clause* joined to the main clause with the help of *that.* The word **any article** is the antecedent, i.e. the word the clause defines. The syntactic function of it is attribute.

Comment: I don't think the preposition "with" and the phrase "patient's body" are part of the antecedent. Please read the sentence again.

Comment: @Rathony right you are. I will correct it. Thank you.

Comment: The antecedent is the word article, not the word any, or the phrase any article.